# CLI (NO GUI) linux distro small memory old pc

Tags: linux, file-server

Can anyone suggest a CLI only light linux distro?
I got a very old machine has 256Ram and 120Gb of HDD. I would like to turn this into a file server only so I can watch movies using my phone.

I don't need a GUI/Desktop Manager. I'll be installing only **nginx**,  **php-fpm**

PS:
I tried DSL, Pupply, TinyCore but I don't like them as they use 80% of my ram after install. I tried install centos 6 minimal but it fails to install because my RAM is too small.

Can you recommend something smaller than them that runs only on CLI. Ubuntu server needs big memory so I remove it on my list.

Note: The current OS of the machine is the MicroXP (used 30% of mem) which runs well but I like to switch for linux for better firewall security.

Comment: I was looking at raspbian stretch but it seems like it's not design for PC. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing **arch** or **linux from scratch**.
You can choose not to install any desktop environment or window manager and they have good learning curve as well.

Comment: I visited before the linux from scratch and I'm thinking of building one but I don't have a time now for that yet...

Comment: The go for arch, it will take less time.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 8 will do it, haven't updated my play vms (which are all 256mb ram) to 9 yet or done a fresh install - been on a BSD kick.

To be honest, I'd also consider getting a Raspberry Pi for this task - will use LOTS less power, be quieter, have more resources, etc.